# Run Command Line from SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Hi I am trying to run a bcp import of a file that is generated from another DB into my DB

(don't ask, long story which ends in me being overruled).

so anyway I have all the constants I need to pass into bcpImport and I have a class that does this in C# but I need to do this via a scheduled run every night. and as I have never ran command line from within SQL scripts (only the other way round, ran scripts from command line) I was wondering if anyone could give me any pointers.

```
MyTable in \"C:\\example\\location\\PartInfo.txt\" -S SQLSERVER2008 -T -f \"example\\location\\FormatFile.xml\"
```

In the interests of completeness I have provided an example of the command line I wish to run

Comment: The requirement of calling the bcp from within SQL is absolute? Couldn't you call bcp directly from your C# code?

Comment: Yes I can and have but the "powers that be" wish this to be called from the SQL Server (believe me discussions like this are common place), The life of a devloper who would want it lol

Comment: God... well, if you can't use xp_cmdshell either, then (and this is just an idea) maybe you could fake it and create a CLR SP that would call the bcp (assuming that is even possible).

Comment: lol I like your think ssarabando but I would have to fake it to the powers that be as well and this I fear is not a possibility, in this case ;) I huess I'm stuck without a reasonabl way, but i will push for xp_cmdshell to be opened up (doubt it but worth a try) and hopefully this may push uis back to my original suggestion of leaving it all in the C# code

Comment: Just remembered about something I've used only once and a long time ago: [Bulk Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx). Wouldn't this do the trick? It's "pure" T-SQL and it doesn't require xp_cmdshell enabled (AFAIK).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [XP_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) but it may have to be [enabled first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190693.aspx).

EDIT:

As the OP dont have admin right, and the  coffee offeres didnt help, maybe creating a job which runs the command could be a reasonable work around, up to [this Link](http://www.sql-server-pro.com/xp_cmdshell.html) this should work properly.

The Idea is creating a job letting it run the command and then delete it, the job looks something like:

```
DECLARE @jobID uniqueidentifier, @cmd varchar(1000) 

SET @cmd = 'the desired shell command'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name = '_JobName', @enabled  = 1, @start_step_id = 1, @owner_login_name='sa', @job_id = @jobID OUTPUT 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id = @jobID, @step_name = 'Description', @step_id = 1, @subsystem = 'CMDEXEC', @command = @cmd

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobID

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_id = @jobID, @output_flag = 0 

WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:05' -- Give the job a chance to complete

IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE name = '_JobName')
BEGIN
     EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name = '_JobName'
END
```

Comment: Thanks @O.D this sounds like what I am looking for, well it did until I found that the network administrator has disabled this. Any other ideas?

Comment: I think i found somehting. A work-around would be to create a SQL Agent job to run the command,  then delete it again.

Comment: I have accpeted your first answer because I feel you were correct with what you answered and in the interests of anyone else viewing this question, They should see the most common way of achieving this, thanks again :)